# Geany и консоль

Tags: geany

Всем привет , я установил Geany на ubuntu , чтобы писать код на c/c++ и я не знаю как открыть консоль , чтобы увидеть результат работы программы. Помогите пожалуйста :D.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что собственно у меня выходит , я компилирую и выполняю , где я получаю результат  непонятно. Говорят , что это должно отображаться где-то внизу  , а где? подскажите пожалуйста , не могу разобраться.

Comment: Я забил на это , так что вопрос закрыт , отныне пользуюсь пичармом

Answer (score 2):

В нижней части окна есть модуль с вкладками "Статус", "Компилятор", "Сообщения" и т.д. Там вкладка с полноценным терминалом.
Еще в настройках можно найти пункт, чтобы stdout отправлялся в новое окно (по умолчанию xterm)

[image: Geany 1.23.1]

Answer (score 2):

Вид > Показывать окно сообщений. Его ещё можно растягивать за верхний край вплоть до нуля пикселей, так что потом легко потерять.

[image: скриншот]